# Loading/ Injecting js in a Single Page Application

Tags: javascript

In a SPA application, after the DOM has loaded with a bundled js file is it possible to asynchronously load a new javascript file right before dynamic contents gets loaded in a page request.

I will like to my bundled.js file very small by keeping only the js files and libraries I need site-wide. On a page that requires a .js file which is not bundled I will somehow like to load the file asynchronously and use the methods provided.

Is this possible and if yes, how is it done.